# ios: selection determine next screen

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, selection

I want to make an application in wich the user first make a couple of choices before going to the following screen. One of the choices is to give a number (probably single roll pickerview) between 0 and 10. Once a number is chosen and also the other choices have been made, the user selects "done". Every number links to a different screen. So 1 links to screen A, 2 links to screen B etc. But I don't know how I can do this. Can somebody please help me? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the delegate method for the selection of the picker view you might want to use some form of switch statement to load and push on the next view controller. You might even decide to load these string values from a plist so the class is more re-useable.

```
NSInteger selectedNumber; //number from picker
NSString *nextViewController = nil;

switch (selectedNumber) {
  case 1:
    nextViewController = @"AViewController";
  break;
  case 2:
    nextViewController = @"BViewController";
  break;
  case 3:
    nextViewController = @"CViewController";
  break;

  //....

  case n:
    nextViewController = @"XViewController";
  break;
  default:
    nextViewController = @"DefaultViewController";
  break;
}

id viewController = [[NSClassFromString(nextViewController) alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Oliver, thanks! One more question (sorry), will the nextViewController appear immediately (in your answer), or must the user select "done" and then the nextViewController will appear?

Comment: @Jan.PetersNL it depends where you put that logic, you could add it as a target to a UIButton so when it is pressed it will go to the next screen, or put it into the `pickerView` delegate to have it go to the viewController on selection.

Answer (score 0):

Have a variable selectedNumber. When user selects value from picker save it in selectedNumber. Then you can use switch to push different views. Or simple if conditions.

```
if(selectedNumber == 1){
push View A
}
else if(selectedNumber == 2){
push View A
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would have done is to delegate the pickerview to my current controller, and implement in it the method :

```
pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:
```

and so with the known row selected, I would redirect the user to the wanted view with if conditions as Durgaprasad said.